# Having issues setting up Liferay 7.4 with Wildfly Application server

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm manually setting up liferay 7.4 with Wildfly 18. I followed the instructions in the link below https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/installation-and-upgrades/installing-liferay/installing-liferay-on-an-application-server/installing-on-wildfly.html

Pls do let me know what's the issue, Should I use different version of Wildfly or I have missed on something, have followed all the steps in the link shared. I have shared the log below for reference. Thanks in Advance!

```
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException   
2022-09-12 04:31:36,908 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ROOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.liferay.portal.configuration.persistence.impl [28]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.upgrade.registry; version=\"3.1.0\"
    -> Export-Package: com.liferay.portal.upgrade.registry; bundle-symbolic-name=\"com.liferay.portal.upgrade.api\"; bundle-version=\"8.0.0\"; version=\"3.1.0\"; uses:=\"com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade\"
       com.liferay.portal.upgrade.api [17]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade; version=\"18.1.0\"

    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.liferay.portal.configuration.persistence.impl [28]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.upgrade.registry; version=\"3.1.0\"
    -> Export-Package: com.liferay.portal.upgrade.registry; bundle-symbolic-name=\"com.liferay.portal.upgrade.api\"; bundle-version=\"8.0.0\"; version=\"3.1.0\"; uses:=\"com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade\"
       com.liferay.portal.upgrade.api [17]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade; version=\"18.1.0\"
"}}
```

Comment: This question is not related to software development (see [help/on-topic]) - there are sites in the stackexchange network where it's on topic - on stackoverflow it's not. Or consider asking it in the Liferay community (https://liferay.dev). [Wildfly 18 is fine](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-portal-7-4-ga41-and-liferay-commerce-4-0-ga41-release)

Comment: Noted. Have asked in liferay.dev ->https://liferay.dev/ask/questions/development/having-issues-setting-up-liferay-7-4-with-wildfly-application-server-1

Comment: Thank you - please stand by, something went wrong with the content moderation on that post, the team is working on it...